# What am I doing wrong with my code, when trying to create an email in iOS? (Help me understand protocols/delegates)

Tags: objective-c, email, ios4

I'm trying to take my "myEmail" class and have it be my "all email methods go here" class, 
and any other class that will email, will use "myEmail". "myEmail" must include MessageUI framework, and
then instiantiate an email controller to animate on the screen.

The complication is that I don't understand how to use "myEmail", which uses "MFMailComposeViewController",
in my "Documents" view correctly. When I call "sendEmail" in my "Documents" class, it never shows the
email window slide into view.

I understand that I can cut out myEmail as the middle man and use the MessageUI framework methods right
in Documents view, but I don't want to go about it in that way.

If anyone could point out how I'm using protocols/delegates wrong, I'd  really appreciate it.

## Code in Question

### This is my myEmail class

In myEmail.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@protocol myEmailDelegate <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
    @required
        -(void)sendEmail;
        - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error;
@end

@interface myEmail : MFMailComposeViewController {
    id <myEmailDelegate> delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> myEmailDelegate;

@end
```

In myEmail.m:

```
#import "myEmail.h"
#import "ConstructionDocuments.h"

@implementation myEmail

@synthesize myEmailDelegate;

-(void)sendEmail
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mypdfdoc" ofType:@"pdf"];  
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  

    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    controller.mailComposeDelegate = myEmailDelegate;
    [controller setSubject:@"Email Example"];
    [controller setMessageBody:@"Attached is pdf." isHTML:NO];
    [controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:filePath];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];  
    [controller release];
}

- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename
{

}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void) dealloc
{ 
    [myEmailDelegate release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

### This is the View where I'll be using my "myEmail" class

In Documents.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "myEmail.h"

@interface Documents : UIViewController <myEmailDelegate> {

}

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> myEmailDelegate;
    - (IBAction)sendEmail;
@end

@protocol myEmailDelegate <myEmailDelegate>
    - (void) sendEmail;
@end
```

In Documents.m:

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail
{
    myEmail *mymyEmail = [[myEmail alloc] init];
    [mymyEmail setmyEmailDelegate: myEmailDelegate];
    [myEmailDelegate sendEmail];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC you need to call `presentModalViewController:` on an "active" view controller which is not the case for you. You could do something like this:

```
-(void)sendEmail:(UIViewController *)externalController
{
    // ...
    [externalController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    // ...
}
```

And then call it from your action (which seems to be inside a view controller):

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail
{
    myEmail *mymyEmail = [[myEmail alloc] init];
    [mymyEmail setmyEmailDelegate:myEmailDelegate];
    [mymyEmail sendEmail:self];
}
```

BTW, class names start with uppercase letter by convention.

Comment: with that code on "[myEmailDelegate sendEmail:self];", I set a breakpoint there, to step into it, and when I try to step into it, it simply doesn't go back to the "myEmail" class to execute the "sendEmail" method. No errors are thrown.

Comment: I don't really understand that, can you try to explain it in another way ? What have you tried ? What's happening ?

Comment: If I put a breakpoint inside "-(void)sendEmail:(UIViewController *)externalController", it never breaks there (yes I have breakpoints enabled). It's like the delegate isn't working, and never calls/fires the "sendEmail" method back in "myEmail.m".

So, in other words, when I click the button in my app, an email compose window never slides into view. Nothing happens, and there is no errors thrown.

Comment: Ah, now I see. The code was wrong. See the corrected version. The `sendEmail:` method belongs to the `myEmail` class and thus the `mymyEmail` variable, not the delegate. Also, since nothing happened, I suspect that `myEmailDelegate` is nil.